# How to use upsert with Prisma?

Tags: database, prisma

I'm trying to either update or create a record in my `Profile` table. I'm using Prisma to define the schema and it looks like this:

```js
model Profile {
  id       String  @id @default(cuid())
  username String?
  about    String?
  url      String?
  company  String?
  userId   String
  user     User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

I'm calling the upsert function like this:

```js
  const createOrUpdateProfile = await prisma.profile.upsert({
      where: { id: id },
      update: {
        username: username,
        about: about,
        url: url,
        company: company,
      },
      create: {
        username: username,
        about: about,
        url: url,
        company: company,
        user: { connect: { id: userId } },
      },
    });
```

I'm getting `userId` from session:

```js
const userId = session.user.id;
```

I'm getting `id`, `username`, `about`, `url`, and `company` from:

```js
//Passed on from await fetch in the form
const { id, username, about, url, company } = req.body;
```

The issue I'm having is, whenever I'm trying to provide the `id`, as in `where: { id: id },` and it is not already in the database, it doesn't create a new record.

If the `id` is not in the database, and I do a `console.log(id)`, it gets back as `undefined`.

If I manually add a record in `Profile` and connect the user, it updates the record when calling the `upsert` function.

Can you help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you specify which record is not found? It does not find the `profile` with `id`? But it finds the `user` with `userId`? Do you get an error?

Comment: @some-user I have updated the original description. I'm getting the `id` from `const { id, username, about, url, company } = req.body; which is from my my fetch function

Comment: The `userId` is coming from the session, and `id` is coming from reg.body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the request body may optionally contain an `id` or be `undefined`. If the `id` is present in the request, you want to update the corresponding record. If it isn't, you want to create a new record.

`upsert` functionality requires a unique identifier that can be used by the database to check whether there is a matching record. The database will then decide what to do. However with an `undefined` value, prisma cannot work.

You could use a key that will not exist in the database in case the value of `id` is `undefined` to make `upsert` insert the record in this case.

```js
await prisma.profile.upsert({
  where: { id: id || '' },
  // ...
});
```

Or you could differentiate the cases and treat them appropriately:

```js
if (id) {
  await prisma.profile.update({
    where: { id },
    data: {
      username,
      about,
      // ...
    },
  });
} else {
  await prisma.profile.create({
    data: {
      username,
      about,
      // ...
    },
  });
}
```

You might want to think about the case that there is an `id` given in the body, but it does exist in the database. Do you want the `update` to fail and reply with an error? Or do you want the database to silently insert? Then use `upsert` instead of `update` above.

Comment: I would like to update a record, if the `id` is found in the database, and if not then it should create a new record as well as connecting it to a user with the `userId`

Comment: I thought that was the whole purpose of using `upsert`?

Comment: To my understanding - correct me - your `id` is `undefined`. So you can't look it up in the database but insert it right away.

Comment: That’s correct. It seems even with your code snippet I’m only able to update a record (given that it is in the database, I.e I manually added it). So I’m back to same behaviour as when I used `upsert` with `where`, `update` and `create` inside it. (See description). 

So, if I’m getting an empty array back when I’m trying to get the record from the `profile` table, and I’m trying to pass  `id` which isn’t there, could that be the issue?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or does the `upsert` silently fail? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I figured out if I added `id || ""`withing the call instead of in the API route, that it worked that way. I still don't know why it didn't work with the API route though.

Comment: Somehow, under the hood Prisma compares the format of the provided `id` in the `where` condition of `upsert` to the format required for the db column. So, if you're using UUIDs for record IDs and you pass an empty string as a fallback when `id` is, say, `null`, then you'll get an error when attempting to create the record (second part of `upsert`). For UUIDs, a fallback `id` value of `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` would work.

Comment: It worked for me, in my case id is an integer, the fallback id for it to create is 0.